# ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.2.0-25-generic: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables

I upgraded Ubuntu 15.10 to **16.04** and somewhere there must happened my trouble.

I firstly realised my trouble when I wanted to do `sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`. There I got:

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.2.0-25-generic/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module ip_tables not found in directory /lib/modules/4.2.0-25-generic
iptables v1.6.0: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

Ok so there is an issue with `/lib/modules/4.2.0-25-generic`...

Then I tried to repair with `sudo depmod`. But I got:

```
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.2.0-25-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
```

Now I wanted to rebuild the kernel with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-...`, here were some versions like:

```
linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic             
linux-image-3.4.0-4-goldfish              
linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic              
linux-image-4.4.0-21-lowlatency           
linux-image-4.4.0-22-generic              
linux-image-4.4.0-22-lowlatency
```

but there is no `linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic`. Strange thing. So by upgrading Linux there was set the old and wrong version of the kernel somehow.

Now I want to see where this version is saved in. And I found it in the `uname -r` command. So `apt-get install linux-image-'uname -r'-dbgsym`, was like:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic-dbgsym
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic-dbgsym'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic-dbgsym'
```

But I have no clue how to change the `uname -r` by hand. And I also don't know why I got this wrong version. And most importantly if it's a good idea to change the `uname`.

Btw I use Digitalocean and upgraded via `do-release-upgrade`.

### Edit #1

I just wanted to see my current kernel. And it is actually 4.4.0-22:

```
sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-22-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-22-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

but uname still says:

```
uname -r
4.2.0-25-generic
```

Can someone explain me what might have happened and how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to **set** the **kernel** in Digitalocean. Now I have the correct kernel (4.4.0.22) and iptables are working, too.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't install your own kernel or kernel modules on a VPS.  You should consult with your host if you absolutely need certain kernel modules.

I think the `filter` module should certainly be included.

Comment: `iptables` is installed. But he does not continue because of `/lib/modules/4.2.0-25-generic`

Comment: Yes, but your kernel doen't have the necessary parts included or available as modules.  You can **not** solve this yourself on a VPS.

Comment: But this cannot be. So my VPS is damaged and there is nothing I can do. As I used the official way of upgrading this would have happened to many others already. And DO is a big company. mhh...

Comment: They are indeed a big company and they offer customer support which you should contact!

Comment: Done and solved :) Added a picture.

Comment: @kwoxer: That's good!  Their configuration is surprisingly flexible.